# How to Creating In-App Purchase Products?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I try to make my In-App Purchase in developer apple. i make step by step follow link: [Creating In-App Purchase Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html)

But i receive a notify in picture: [image]

But i want to make the same picture: [image]

Please help me the step i must do. Thank you for all the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are experiencing an UI issue. I just logged into iTunes Connect and create a new app and in-app purchase and it looks fine.

[image]

**What you can do:**

- try a different browser (Chrome / Safari / Firefox)
- reload the page
- contact the iTunes Connect team